# Can I glue D rings to the back of a frameless mirror

Tags: mounting

Can I glue D rings to the back of a frameless mirror? I don't want to use mounting clips nor glue it to the wall. I'd like to hang it from a stone wall using brick clips. I'm trying to do as little damage to the wall as possible.
Thank-you, Lucie

Comment: Seems like that would put all the stress in a few places and put the mirror at high risk of breaking. It would also depend on finding an adhesive that will strongly bond without showing through the back of the mirror.

Comment: How big is the mirror? How many D-rings? How big is the gluable surface?

Answer (score 4):

Can you? You *could*... but I would advise against it.

A better option (depending where your skill set lies) is to make a frame for it, **or** glue the mirror to a piece of wood that you can then attach fasteners to. You could use a piece of plywood for instance, which is cut smaller than the mirror (2 inches on each side is probably plenty) so you don't see the edges unless you're right against the wall. Attach the D-rings to the plywood with brackets (like these) [image]

Comment: Upvoted. Just to mention that there is specific glue for mirrors that won't show through. And use lots -- I had a mirror come crashing down after years of staying stuck.